# Converting string column to date format in datatable frame in python

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, date-manipulation, py-datatable

For an easy example :

```
import datatable as dt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

d_t = dt.Frame(pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["04/05/2020", "04/06/2020"]}))
```

There is only a column named Date with two values in str32 type.

How could I convert the Date column into a Date Format in datatable frame.

I have tried

```
dates_list = [datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y") for date in d_t["Date"].to_list()[0]]
d_t[:,"NewDate"] = dt.Frame(dates_list)
d_t["NewDate"].max()
# The code can run successfully so far.
```

But the result was shown like this :

```
     NewDate
    ▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪
  0     NA
```

I think it was still not a date format.

Even I looked up the type of each column, I still have no idea:

```
d_t.stypes

[Out]: (stype.str32, stype.obj64)
```

Is there any way to solve the problem or any alternatives?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: did you try to convert the column with `pd.to_datetime()` first?

Comment: It was a `datatable frame` object, so i can't directly use `pd.to_datetime`. So i extract the column and turned it into list or array and then convert it with `pd.to_datetime`, it had successfully turned into datetime format but when I combind the array or the list back to the datatable frame, it change into str32 automatically.

Comment: Right now this is impossible because datatable doesn't support datetime column type yet.

Comment: OK! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[datatable 1.0](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/v1.0.0.html?highlight=date#v1.0.0) introduced new column types [`datatable.Type.date32`](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/type/date32.html) and [`datatable.Type.time64`](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/type/time64.html).

In this case conversion from the string column `Date` to `date32` type works like this:

```
d_t[:, dt.update(Date_date = 
             dt.time.ymd(dt.as_type(dt.str.slice(dt.f.Date, 6, 10), int), 
                         dt.as_type(dt.str.slice(dt.f.Date, 3, 5), int), 
                         dt.as_type(dt.str.slice(dt.f.Date, 0, 2), int)))]

d_t

    Date        Date_date
    ▪▪▪▪        ▪▪▪▪
0   04/05/2020  2020-05-04
1   04/06/2020  2020-06-04
```

Although a bit verbose it performs all operations inside datatable without overhead and penalty of intermediate lists or pandas frames. Hopefully, future releases will add more functions beyond [`datatable.time.ymd()`](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/time/ymd.html) to simplify such conversion ops.

Have you picked the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) to represent dates (i.e. string in the format `%Y-%m-%d`) then conversion to `date32` would have been considerably simpler:

```
d_t = dt.Frame({"Date": ["2020-04-05", "2020-04-06"]})
d_t[0] = dt.Type.date32
d_t.stypes

> (stype.date32,)
```

Comment: Thanks for the information of the new features introduced in the latest version issued. This seems great!

Comment: glad you found this useful. For a bit more info see my latest post where I put together a brief overview of date/time functionality in v1.0: https://novyden.blogspot.com/2021/07/time-travel-with-py-datatable-10.html